# Python: How do I write multiple lists to one file?

Tags: python, file, list

Lets say I have a list of students, a list of test scores, and a list of averages. How do I write each of these lists to one file formatted so that the first student, test scores, and average will be on line one, the second student, test scores, and average will be on line two, etc.?

Comment: Come one, what's the code you've attempted?

Comment: I tried to do this: 
        output_file=('fou', 'w')
 line1=names[1], ID[1], Income[1], tax[1]
 output_file.write(line1)

just to create the first line but I'd need to create a loop to have it retrieve the first lines from each list, then the second lines from each list, etc. and I was looking for a more streamlined way to do it.

Comment: Hint: try `zip()` and then iterate and print to file

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
with open("file.txt","w") as f:
    for (student,score,avg) in zip(students,scores,avgs):
        f.write("{0},{1},{2}\n".format(student,score,avg))
```

If you don't want to use a for loop, you could look at [csv.writer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer), but that's hardly more "streamlined" than what I've posted here.

Comment: csv writer is overkill unless you expect commas, quotes etc in the input.

Comment: @gnibbler definitely, I was responding to his comment on the question that said he wanted to avoid looping.

Comment: ah, ok. I added one to my answer using `map`

Comment: @kevinsa5 do you think it's better to use a loop? I'm very new to programming. I've never used zip before.

Comment: What I've posted is what nearly every experienced programmer would "go-to" for this problem. Loops are something to love in python, it lends itself nicely to iteration. :)

Answer (score 1):

Without a `for loop`

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(map("{},{},{}\n".format, students, scores, avgs))
```

Comment: This won't work for non-string types, and it's not unreasonable to think `scores` and `avgs` might be numbers.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote and _delete_?

Comment: Could you please tell us how put format to each {} column? Thanks

Comment: I got it. Who is interested here the answer in Format Examples section: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html